# iOS Memory Management

Tags: objective-c

Leaks is telling me that the following is a memory leak, but I'm not sure why.

TitledArray.h

```
@interface TitledArray : NSObject {

NSMutableArray *realArray;
BOOL uniqueTitles;
BOOL uniqueIDs;

}

@property (nonatomic) BOOL uniqueTitles;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL uniqueIDs;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *realArray;
```

TitledArray.m

```
-(id)init {
return [self initWithUniqueTitles:FALSE uniqueIDs:FALSE];
}

-(id)initWithUniqueTitles:(BOOL)titles uniqueIDs:(BOOL)IDs {

if ( self = [super init] ) {
  //self.realArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  self.realArray = [NSMutableArray array];
  self.uniqueTitles = titles;
  self.uniqueIDs = IDs;
}
return self;
}
```

MissionLoading.h

```
@interface MissionLoading : TitledObject {


TitledArray *storageWeights;
TitledArray *passengerWeights;

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) FloatArray *storageWeights;
@property (nonatomic, retain) FloatArray *passengerWeights;
```

MissionLoading.m

```
@synthesize storageWeights;
@synthesize passengerWeights;


-(id)init {
if ( self = [super init]) {


    self.storageWeights = [[TitledArray alloc] initWithUniqueTitles:FALSE uniqueIDs:TRUE];
    self.passengerWeights = [[TitledArray alloc] initWithUniqueTitles:FALSE uniqueIDs:TRUE];

}

return self;
}

-(void)dealloc{

[storageWeights release];
[passengerWeights release];

[super dealloc];
}
```

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < recordCount; i++)
{
    loading = [[MissionLoading alloc] init];

    // add to array

    [loading release];
}
```

The root leak is in the TitledArray object with self.realArray = [NSMutableArray array];

I'm still quite new to iOS development, but this looks good to me. Any thoughts would be helpful. I can provide more information if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning to a property that has `retain` in the `@property` declaration, the synthesized setter retains the value already, so autorelease the thing that you are assigning to the property, like so:

```
-(id)init {
    if ( self = [super init]) {
        self.storageWeights = [[[TitledArray alloc] initWithUniqueTitles:FALSE uniqueIDs:TRUE] autorelease];
        self.passengerWeights = [[[TitledArray alloc] initWithUniqueTitles:FALSE uniqueIDs:TRUE] autorelease];
    }
    // ....
}
```

Comment: That was the problem. I probably would have never figured that out! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you had a  //self.realArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; in the init. Do a clean build and then run the tools again. That old code might have been in there for some reason and would certainly be flagged as a leak.

One other thing, put `self.realArray = nil` in the `dealloc` of TitledArray.

Comment: I did both suggestions, and it still is saying that it is leaking :(